# How to perform data flow analysis on function parameters in IR

Tags: llvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyNPm.png)
How to determine whether a GEP instruction, when accessing a structure member, originates directly or indirectly from a function parameter?

What I think of is the conversion of one instruction and one instruction, but there are too many cases, and the specific IR scenarios are not fully considered. It doesn't feel like a good solution. Is there any good way to solve similar problems?